# Difference in layouts composing for older Android OS versions

Tags: android

Are there any things that I should keep in mind while composing a layout to support for older OSes including Froyo? Is the flow of layout construction the same comparing to the very new OS version? The reason I'm asking is because I have some deviations between layouts on newer and older versions.

Comment: "I have some deviations between layouts on newer and older versions" -- you may wish to edit your question to explain what those "deviations" are, so we have some idea what you think "the flow of construction" is.

Answer (score 0):

See this video [Multi-Versioning Android User Interfaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amZM8oZBgfk&list=PL56D792A831D0C362&index=12)

This will show you how to build user interfaces that work consistently across Android versions, from Eclair to today. We'll cover topics including the Action Bar, Fragments, style, size qualifiers, app structure, and navigation.